# Getting error saving Sharedpreference in Boolean format

Tags: java, android, boolean, sharedpreferences

Getting an error when saving shared preferences after reading

```
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    mUserLearneddrawer = Boolean.valueOf(readPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,"false"));

}
 public static void readPreferences(Context context,String prefernceName,String defaultValue) {
    SharedPreferences sharedPrefernces = context.getSharedPreferences(PREF_FILE_NAME, Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
    SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPrefernces.edit();
    editor.putString(prefernceName, defaultValue);
    editor.apply();
}
```

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: can not resolve method valueOf(void).

Comment: Also share more code, specifically the method **readPreferences** and the place where it's being called.

Comment: That means mate that the method `readPreferences` return type is void, it does not return a value. Either get it to return what is in the preferences or do not use it in this way. Share more code and we can help you further.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're getting an Exception thrown because you're trying to get a `Boolean.valueOf(void)` because your `readPreferences` method returns void, and not `Boolean` or `bool`. In order to fix this, you will need to change that method to return what it has read from the preferences. That should look something like this:

```
public bool readPreferences(Context ctx, String key, boolean default){
     return ctx.getSharedPreferences.getBoolean(key, default);
}
```

**EDIT**

As I can see from your edited question, you're actually **writing** the value in a method called `readPreferences` which is very counter-intuitive. Anyway, since you're just writing a value and applying just do this:

```
@Override
public void onCreate( Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    readPreferences(getActivity(),KEY_USER_LEARNED_DRAWER,"false");
}
```

Do not assign this value to anything, because this does not return anything (returns `void`).

Comment: Vucko.I'm changing return type to String.

Comment: Well in that case, be careful because `valueOf` might throw an exception if it cannot parse the value from your String. I'd recommend changing the return type to `bool` if you need bool.